Why apptainer images lack files under /usr/share/info and /use/share/man/man*?
Following examples in the documentation, I experimented with apptainer containers with Fedora 40 and Almalinux 9.4.  In all cases, the containers were missing the files in /usr/share/info and /use/share/man/man* despite the package system rpm reports many files to be installed there.
Why is that?
Is it possible to modify the container settings to allow writing and persistently store files on those folders? I can write and persistently update other folders but not those ones.
I have done:
apptainer build --fix-perms --sandbox fedora-40 docker:fedora:40

Apparently this is a working Fedora 40 system, however it is missing all files in /usr/share/info and /use/share/man/man*. Here is a session:
apptainer run --no-home --no-mount bind-paths --cleanenv   --fakeroot fedora-40 bash
Apptainer> ls -l /usr/share/man/man1
total 0
Apptainer> rpm -ql bash | grep /usr/share/man/man1 | grep umask
/usr/share/man/man1/umask.1.gz
Apptainer> ls -l /usr/share/man/man1/umask.1.gz
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/man/man1/umask.1.gz': No such file or directory


The same happens with docker:almalinux:9.4.
The same happens with

apptainer version 1.3.2-1.fc40 in Fedora 40
apptainer version 1.1.7-1.fc38 in Fedora 38 using micromamba

and also when running with --writable.
I note that man and info are not installed. I can install man with "dnf install man" when running with writable, but the of course:
Apptainer> man umask
No manual entry for umask

I found no documentation or information searching the web about these features of apptainer. I observe the same behaviour also in podman, using the fedora:40 docker image.
